# Firebase Admin SDK Google HTTP Client Request and Response logging

Tags: java, spring, firebase, log4j2, slf4j

Firebase Admin SDK is using logging through slf4j and my project has been set up with Log4j2. Usually I do the integrations through custom clients wrapped around RestTemplate with specific logging logic to log http requests and responses in specific standardized format (defined through xml).

The problem is that now I have stumbled upon an integration where I actually could use a SDK, but the problem is that my logging is not very easily compatible with Google HTTP client. I have skimmed through various sites to look for good practices, but unfortunately I haven't found anything tangible.

**How to setup Log4j2 file appender for Google HTTP Client to output request and response logs in standardized format?** Thankful for the good practices and points for directing towards new knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a Logging handler to this class:
`com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport`, a similar approach is outlined in the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-http-java-client/http-transport.html), and extracting the request and response data from the log records. The problem with this approach is that the data is in textual format, since it's a log record after all, and would need to be parsed again.

I think the safest and most flexible approach in this case would be to make use of the request and interceptor functionality provided by the library. So, we can add our own logging logic before and after the request. This way all of the request and response data is available.

Here's some example code for this:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.*;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyLogger {
    static class MyInitializer implements HttpResponseInterceptor, HttpRequestInitializer, HttpExecuteInterceptor {

        @Override
        public void interceptResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            // perform response logging here
            var request = response.getRequest();
            System.out.println(
                "RESPONSE: " + request.getRequestMethod() + " " + request.getUrl() + " " + response.getStatusCode()
            );

        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.setResponseInterceptor(this);
            request.setInterceptor(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void intercept(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            // perform request logging here
            System.out.println("REQUEST: " + request.getRequestMethod() + " " + request.getUrl());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(new MyInitializer());
      var request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("http://example.com"));
      request.execute();
    }
}
```